# How do I properly read a line of a file into an array?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, curl, sed

I have a file like this:

```
1234 1234 "First Name" "Last Name"
```

And I have a bash function like this:

```
function somePeoples()
{
  body='"id":"'$1'","num":"'$2'","name":"'$3'","lname":"'$4'"'
  echo $body
}
```

Which is contained in a bash script that I would source in the command line. After which, I do the following to test the function:

```
$ arr=(1234 1234 "First Name" "Last Name")
$ somePeoples "{arr[@]}"
$ "id":"1234","num":"1234","name":"First Name","lname":"Last Name"
$ somePeoples "${arr[0]}" "${arr[1]}" "${arr[2]}" "${arr[3]}"
$ "id":"1234","num":"1234","name":"First Name","lname":"Last Name"
```

Now let's go back to the file which contains lines like this:

```
input.txt:
1234 1234 "First Name" "Last Name"
2234 2234 "Some other name" "Some other last name"
```

I try to read each line in the file via a for loop with a limited count because I know exactly how many lines in the file. The trick is to read each line and put each line into an array to be passed to the somePeoples function. So I make a script that sources the other script with the function. Let's just call it the client script and let's pretend that it's actually looping:

```
the client script:
arr=(`sed -n "1p" input.txt`)
somePeoples "${arr[@]}"
```

But to my horror the output is:

```
$ "id":"1234","num":"1234","name":""First,"lname":"Name""
```

Also, trying to do these yields the same result

```
somePeoples "${arr[0]}" "${arr[1]}" "${arr[2]}" "${arr[3]}"
somePeoples `sed -n "1p" input.txt`
```

What's the difference? When I type it out at the command line with the same quoting patterns it works fine, but not when I read the input from the file and pass it to some array or directly to the function. Why does it break on spaces even though the arguments are quoted? And, err, how can I prevent that from happening?

I'm actually trying to prepare a request body to be passed to cURL in jSON format and the input parameters are contained in a file hundreds of lines long. But I think the cURL stuff is irrelevant for this question since I reproduced the problem through bash alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you say, the original data-file is in CSV format, then you're probably better off doing something simple like

```
IFS=, while read id num name lname; do
    ...
done <input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really get at the issue of why quoting doesn't work (I assume you tried single quotes), but if a quick and dirty solution is acceptable, you could convert the spaces to something else via regexp, and back into spaces when needed

Comment: Actually I think I made a mistake. The original input file is a csv file with quoted values per column. I regexed commas to spaces and, well, I fail. Thanks for the suggestion. I think spaces are not the right delimiters for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is what I did after converting the input file into a csv:

```
ORIG_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en ",")
arr=(`sed -ns "1p" input.txt`) # nvm the extension
IFS=$ORIG_IFS
somePeoples "${arr[@]}"
```

This yields the output:

```
"id":"1234","num":"1234","name":""First Name"","lname":""Last Name""
```

The quoted strings got double double quoted. Almost close. Maybe I need to clean up the input file first?

```
sed -e 's/"//g' < input.txt > input.txt.new
```

And then that's what I used to finally get the output that I want. Thanks guys :) Never knew about IFS 'till now.

Comment: There's no reason to use `echo` to set `IFS`, just do `IFS=,` or `IFS=','`.